# How to run a privileged Docker container with the Jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've been trying for a while to run a privileged container in a Jenkins Declarative Pipeline, but I can't find out the syntax or any examples in the docs. What I have so far, with a un-privileged container:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage("Build") {
            agent {
                docker { image "hello-world" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems like a common use-case, I can't believe nobody ran into it already :(

Comment: Under https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent you can find a quite comprehensive documentation about that.

Comment: Thanks, found it a bit later after posting the question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please refer the example below:

```
 stage('Update dependencies version') {
        agent {
            docker {
                image 'maven'
                args '--privileged -v $HOME/.m2:/home/jenkins/.m2 -ti -u 496 -e MAVEN_CONFIG=/home/jenkins/.m2 -e MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx2048m'
            }
        }

        when {
            not {
                branch 'master'
            }
        }

        steps {
            script {
                ....
            }
        }
    }
```

Or at the top level:

```
 pipeline {
        agent {
            docker {
                image 'maven'
                args '--privileged -v $HOME/.m2:/home/jenkins/.m2 -ti -u 496 -e MAVEN_CONFIG=/home/jenkins/.m2 -e MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx2048m'
            }
        }
        stages {
            stage('Build') {
                steps {
                    script {
                        maven.cleanPackage()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Or inside script under stage:

```
        stage('Build') {
        agent {
            label 'jenkins-slave-swat-prod-01'
        }

        steps {
            script {
                docker.image('mysql:latest').withRun('-e "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password" -e "MYSQL_DATABASE=scheduler" -p 3306:3306') { c ->
                    docker.image('maven').inside("--privileged -v $HOME/.m2:/home/jenkins/.m2 -ti -u 496 -e MAVEN_CONFIG=/home/jenkins/.m2 -e MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx2048m --link ${c.id}:localhost") {
                        maven.cleanPackage()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing you mean that I can add the args "--privileged" option to the docker block. That worked, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: yup. you are right. sorry forgot to mention. glad it worked!! Please accept the answer if that helped

Comment: I've edited your comment to add the flag and accepted the answer :)

Comment: Could you edit your answer to pinpoint this detail?